# rails + devise - When a User Registers, remember_me is not set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

How can I make it so that when a user registers, the remember_me setting is set with devise?

Right now what's happening is a user joins the site, and then when they come back later they have to log in which is not a good experience.

I want remember_me to be set to true by default when a user registers.

ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the devise documentation, generate your devise views and in the sign_in view/partial set the value of the checkbox to true